# EditableGrid - show search filter & pagination using javascript

Tags: javascript, search, filter, grid, editablegrid

I am using EditableGrid to create a grid dynamically using Javascript.

I am able to display the grid properly.
But can anyone please tell me, how do i add the search filter(search box) & pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<input type="text" id="searchField" />
```

```
var myGrid= new EditableGrid("myGrid", {
    // Whatever options you chose
});

var searchField = document.getElementById('searchField');
searchField.addEventListener(
    'keyup',
    function (){
        myGrid.filter(searchField.value);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi @Cerbrus , I didn't run the code yet. But I think this should work, provided there is something like the 'filter' method. What are the possible options? (//Whatever options u chose). And where can I find the documentation of EditableGrid? Please help..

Comment: [Here's the documentation](http://www.editablegrid.net/documentation/index.html). I assumed you had a grid setup already. Take a look at [this demo](http://www.editablegrid.net/editablegrid/examples/full/index.html) (Also, yes, there is a `filter` function)

Comment: Btw, I have already created the grid. Right now I am not near my machine. Where do I find the code for what I see on the demo page?

Comment: The page source links to [this js file](http://www.editablegrid.net/editablegrid/examples/full/javascript/demo.js)

Comment: Hi Cerbrus, I just created another dummy grid and checked the search filter. It works..!! Thank you.. : )

Comment: Hi Cerbrus, have another question for you. :) Instead of pagination, can I add scroll-bar within the grid, so that I can scroll down/up to view the records. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's probably possible, but I don't know how that'd be done with that grid library.

Comment: Hi Cerbrus,I know that we can set icons/images in Editable grid. I used the datatype as 'html'.It worked for me & I could display icons.But wasn't able to sort the column by clicking the column header.I then decided to display the icon using the setCellRenderer.Came across this piece of code: `setCellRenderer("country", new CellRenderer({
   render: function(cell, value){ cell.innerHTML = value ? "<img src='" + image("flags/" + value.toLowerCase() + ".png") + "' alt='" + value + "'/>" : ""; }
  }));` And its not working for me.Not able to display icons using setCellRenderer method.